# Broadleaf: No bean named 'blMainEntityActionsExtensionManager' is defined

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, broadleaf-commerce

I've got the [BroadLeaf demo application](https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/DemoSite) and tried to modify using [this manual](http://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/broadleaf-concepts/admin/admin-custom-controllers). I added a class like that:

```
package com.myco.admin.web.controller;
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class MyController extends AdminAbstractController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String test(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model) throws Exception {
        // This is expected by the modules/emptyContainer template, this is a custom template that gets included into the body
        model.addAttribute("customView", "views/test");

        // ensure navigation gets set up correctly
        setModelAttributes(model, "test");

        // gets the scaffolding set up to display the template from the customView attribute above
        return "modules/emptyContainer";
    }
}
```

And when I try to run `admin.war`, I can see the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myController': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'blMainEntityActionsExtensionManager' is defined
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:434)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.extensibility.MergeContextLoader.contextInitialized(MergeContextLoader.java:148)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'blMainEntityActionsExtensionManager' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1168)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:281)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:461)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:435)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:559)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:169)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:305)
    ... 23 more
```

What's wrong with this example? I guess it should work out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception would get resolved if you add the following lines in applicationContext-admin.xml:

```
<bean id="blMainEntityActionsExtensionManager" class="org.broadleafcommerce.openadmin.web.controller.MainEntityActionsExtensionManager" />
<bean id="blAdminAbstractControllerExtensionManager" class="org.broadleafcommerce.openadmin.web.controller.AdminAbstractControllerExtensionManager" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace seems to indicate that you did not register the bean/controller in the applicationContext-servlet-admin.xml file. Make sure the admin application is aware of your new controllers by adding something like this in the applicationContext-servlet-admin.xml file.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myco.admin.web.controller" />
```

Comment: It does not make any difference